# WPF DataGrid column style ignores IsTabStop false

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have an usercontrol with a datagrid which contains two columns.

The user wants 1. clicks in the second column cell, 2. edit the value, 3. presses the tab key to get in the next row (second column cell), 4. edit the call value in second row

But the user has to press the tab key twice, so I assume the "IsTabStop" in the first column is not working.

I browsed through the internet, everybody claims following lines should work, but they are not working for me. Does anybody knows why?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    ...
    <Style x:Key="DataGridLabelCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridValueCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ValueType}" Value="Text">
                ...
                <TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.Value, .../>
                ...
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ValueType}" Value="DateTime">
                ...
                <c1:C1DatePicker Text="{Binding Value}" />
                ...
            </DataTrigger>
            ...
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

...
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Name}" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridLabelCellStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridValueCellStyle}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
...
```

Comment: Where do you tab from and is name the first or second column? You should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue when asking a question.

Comment: Hi mm8, this comment was helpful, now I know, why it was downvoted
You are right!

Comment: I tried to write the problem in a better way, sorry ...

Answer (score 0):

I found it by myself, it is my fault.

- I inserted an additional TextBox control (via DataTemplate)
- So I have to add simply an additional IsTabStop = false for the second datagrid column
- Then it is working

```
 <Style x:Key="DataGridLabelCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
     <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
 </Style>
 <Style x:Key="DataGridValueCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
     **<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>**
     <Style.Triggers>
          ...
```